# Doctrine create setters and getters?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

OK, I am missing something here ...
I want to start using Doctrine 2.
Now I created an entity class "recepie" with annotations:

```
/**
* @Entity
*/

class recepie 
{

  /**
  * @Id @Column(type="integer")
  * @GeneratedValue
  */
  private $id;

  /** @Column(length=500) */
  private $titleDE;

  /** @Column(length=4000) */
  private $descDE;

  /** @Column(length=4000) */
  private $instructDE;

  /** @Column(type="date") */
  private $postedAt;

  /** @Column(type="integer") */
  private $skill;

  /** @Column(type="integer") */
  private $prepTime;

  /** @Column(type="smallint") */
  private $personNum;

  /** @Column(type="boolean") */
  private $isPublic;


}
```

Now I try to auto generate setters and getters using:

```
php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities entities/
```

Now this creates a new file called "recipie.php~", probably not to overwrite the existing recipie.php file that contains the initial entity.

What is the idea here ? Am I supposed to open that file and copy/paste the getters and setters into my initial entity class ?
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is on the right track, but not quite right. Actually `generate-entities` *does* modify your existing entity file, and those files with `~` appended to their names are just backup files that `generate-entities` creates beforehand.

The accessor methods should be created in the original file. If everything looks okay, you can delete the backup file. You shouldn't have to copy and paste anything from it. If you want to run `generate-entities` without creating those files, you can use the `--no-backup` option.

Comment: I am just plain stupid !! I had the entity file open in an editor and I simply couldn't see the changes without reopening it.
So sorry ...

Comment: Nah, not stupid. It's an easy mistake to make. Depending on your editor, you may be able to see the changes without reopening the file by just switching to a different tab and back. (I have to do that sometimes in Sublime Text. Other times, it loads the changes without me doing anything - not sure why.)